# validation of unque key of data base from ajax in php form without refreshing content of form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show an error message of validation that phone is already registered and redirect to the same form without refreshing the data entered in form text fields.

How can I do that?

```js
<?php
include 'connection.php';


$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['address']);

$user_query = "INSERT INTO `user`( `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`,`address`)"
        . " VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$phone','$address')";
$user_query_submit = mysqli_query($con, $user_query);
if($user_query_submit === TRUE)
    {
        header( "Location:index.php" ); 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>
        alert('This phone is already registered');
       window.location.href='sign_up.php';
       </script>";
    }

       
  ?>
```

```html
<form role="form" action="sign_up.php" method="post">
              <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First name" required="true">
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"  name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required="true">
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
                </div><div class="form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Contact</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter contact no" required="true">
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address"> Address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required="true">
                </div>
                  
                
                

              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

So how can show error message box without refreshing form in my form?

When I click ok button in error MSG box all entries of my of my form are refreshed and I want to see all my entries same in form.

Can some help me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% what the question is. Is it just how to post your form data without refreshing? If so, then all you need to do is use AJAX

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax form validation with php and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279909/ajax-form-validation-with-php-and-javascript)

Comment: using ajax how could i do that i hardly know about ajax or javascript

Answer (score 0):

try this code and about the validation on the phone you should primary key the phone

it should be like this
[image]

got the idea on this page you should check it out to learn mode about ajax

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@sogata/how-to-insert-data-to-mysql-from-php-using-jquery-ajax

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="box-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="first-name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter First name" required="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"  name="last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
</div><div class="form-group">
<label for="phone">Contact</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter contact no" required="true">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="address"> Address</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required="true">
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
<button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                var first_name =$("#first_name").val();
                var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
                var email=$("#email").val();
                var phone=$("#phone").val();
                var Address=$("#Address").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'fetch.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        first_name:first_name,
                        last_name:last_name,
                        email:email,
                        phone:phone,
                        Address:Address
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                       document.location.href = "help.php";
                   }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php

$conn =new mysqli("localhost","root","","yourdatabase");
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['Address'];

$user_query = "INSERT INTO `user`( `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`,`address`)"
        . " VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$phone','$address')";
if($conn->query($user_query ) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "Data Inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Contact Should be Unique";
    }


  ?>
```

Comment: after duplicate entry of phone i want to redirect to form which is index.php  with same entry i have entered can i do that

Comment: @Ayushsinghthakur i edited the answer just copy it out.

Comment: @Ayushsinghthakur change document.location.href = "fetch.php" into this document.location.href = "index.php" sorry